# Simple harmonic motion in uniform circular motion as a projection along $x$-axis

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

[image]

The image shows the position of particle at $t=0$ and $t=t$, and the relevant angles are labelled. The radius of the circle is A. When I try to find $x(t)$ I can directly resolve along the negative $x$ axis leading to $x = -A\cos(\omega t)$. However, using the general equation of this type of motion: $x = A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$, where $\phi =\frac{\pi}{2}$, I get the simplification as $x=A\cos(\omega t)$ using $\cos(\omega t) = \sin(\omega t+\frac{\pi}{2})$.Why do I get two different answers?

Comment: You have to measure the angle with respect to the positive direction of the x-axis in the anticlockwise sense. Here your initial angular displacement is $\pi$ radians and hence you are getting the negative sign.

Answer (score 1):

You get different answers because, for some reason, you have taken your phase constant, $\phi$, to be $\frac{\pi}2$ whereas you should have taken it to be $–\frac{\pi}2$.

$$\text{then}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ x=A\sin \left(\omega t-\frac{\pi}2\right)= -\cos \omega t$$

For example, when $t=0$, $x=\sin \left(-\frac{\pi}2\right)=0$